# Cypher query doesn't return all the expected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this graph:

```
A<-B->C
```

B is the root of a tiny tree. There is exactly one relation between A and B, and one between B and C.

When I run the following, one node is returned. Why does this Cypher query not return the A and C nodes?

```
MATCH(a {name:"A"})<-[]-(rewt)-[]->(c) RETURN c
```

It would seem to be that the first half of that query would find the root, and the second half would find both child nodes.

Until a few minutes ago, I would have thought it logically identical to the following query which works. What's the difference?

```
MATCH (a {name:"A"})<-[]-(rewt)
MATCH (rewt)-[]->(c)
RETURN c
```

**EDIT for cybersam**

I have abstracted my database so we could discuss my specific issue.  Now, we still have a tiny tree, but there are 4 nodes that are children of the root.(Sorry this is different, but I'm developing and don't want to change my environment too much.)

This query returns all 4:

```
match(a)<-[]-(b:ROOT)-[]->(c) return c
```

One of them has a name of "dddd"...

```
match(a {name"dddd"})<-[]-(b:ROOT)-[]->(c) return c
```

This query only returns *three* of them. "dddd" is not included. omg.

To answer cybersam's specific question, this query:

```
MATCH (a {name:"dddd"})<--(rewt:CODE_ROOT)
MATCH (rewt)-->(c)
RETURN a = c;
```

Returns four rows. The values are `true, false, false, false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

There is a difference between your 2 queries. A `MATCH` clause will filter out all duplicate relationships.

Therefore, your first query would filter out all matches where the left-side relationship is the same as the right-side relationship:

```
MATCH(a {name:"A"})<--(rewt)-->(c)
RETURN c;
```

Your second query would allow the 2 relationships to be the same, since the relationships are found by 2 separate `MATCH` clauses:

```
MATCH (a {name:"A"})<--(rewt)
MATCH (rewt)-->(c)
RETURN c;
```

If I am right, then the following query should return `N` rows (where `N` is the number of outgoing relationships from `rewt`) and only one value should be `true`:

```
MATCH (a {name:"A"})<--(rewt)
MATCH (rewt)-->(c)
RETURN a = c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will you clarify your last sentence? Do you mean with respect to the first query?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my answer with a query that you can perform to see if I am right.

Comment: I had misread your question a bit, so I have updated my answer yet again.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea that if one identified a node, it would be excluded from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Both work just fine for me. I've tried on 2.3.0 Community.
Do you mind posting your CREATE command ?

Answer (score 0):

In each `MATCH` clause, each relationship will be matched only once. See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html for reference.

See this related question as well: [What does a comma in a Cypher query do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089692/what-does-a-comma-in-a-cypher-query-do)