# Check node exists before continuing with rest of query in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have an endpoint `getAlbumsByUserId` which as you can imagine, returns all albums created by a user.

I have the query working and it returns the correct nodes:

```
"MATCH (u:User "+user+")",
"MATCH (m:User {uuid: '"+userId+"'})",
"OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[:CREATED]->(n:Asset:Album)<-[r:CAN_READ]-()<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(u)",
"RETURN DISTINCT collect(n) AS nodes, collect(m) AS user",
"UNION",
"MATCH (m:User {uuid: '"+userId+"'})",
"OPTIONAL MATCH (i:User "+user+")-[f:CREATED]->(n:Asset:Album)",
"RETURN DISTINCT collect(n) AS nodes, collect(m) AS user"
```

What this query does is finds all `Albums` that can the user `(m)` created AND what the user `(u)` can read based on its relationship to a role that can read the `Album`

Because there is no direct `:CAN_READ` relationship from a `User` to an `Album` and not every `Album` can be read by a `Role`, I need to also check albums with a `:CREATED` relationship to the `User` that is making the request.

Is there a simple way to check that

`"MATCH (m:User {uuid: '"+userId+"'})"`

exists before running the rest of the query so that I have a useful response to tell the controller/user?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would use [Cypher Parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) rather than concatenating the data into the string directly to prevent injection attacks.

I think that you need to combine your first two `MATCH` clauses into one:

```
MATCH (u:User {uuid: {userId}}), (m:User {uuid: {currentUserId}})
```

This means that you'll only get a match if everything in that clause is found.

See also [What does a comma in a Cypher query do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089692/what-does-a-comma-in-a-cypher-query-do/34090944).

If that doesn't work you might first simply get all albums which the current user has access to and then match against the given user (simplified query):

```
MATCH (current_user:User {uuid: {currentUserId}})-[:BELONGS_TO]->()-[:CAN_READ]->(album:Asset:Album)
WITH album
MATCH (user:User {uuid: {userId}})-[:CREATED]->(album)
RETURN album
```