# What does a query with 2 MATCH clauses do and how is it different from a query with a single MATCH clause that has 2 distinct paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I don't understand how two queries work in [this](http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.0-M05/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html) page of the neo4j doc.

First, here is the graph:

[image]

Here is the first query I don't understand:

```
MATCH (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]-(friend)
MATCH (friend)-[r2:FRIEND]-(friend_of_a_friend)
RETURN friend_of_a_friend.name AS fofName
```

Which gives the result of "David", "Adam".

I had expected the result to be "David" only because the first `MATCH` clause would give the "Pernilla" node, which the second `MATCH` clause will use to give the "David" node.

Can someone please walk me through how the above query actually works?

The second query I don't understand is:

```
MATCH (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]-(friend),(friend)-[r2:FRIEND]-(friend_of_a_friend)
RETURN friend_of_a_friend.name AS fofName
```

Since the documentation (up to this point) did not talk about how a `MATCH` clause with two distinct patterns work, I really thought the above query is equivalent to the first query too. Can I get a walkthrough on how this query works so that I can see how it is different from  the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `MATCH` or `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause in Cypher, you can be guaranteed that, for any given matching of that path, no relationship will be used twice.  Thus if you did:

```
MATCH (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]-(friend)-[r2:FRIEND]-(friend_of_a_friend)
```

or alternatively:

```
MATCH
  (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]-(friend),
  (friend)-[r2:FRIEND]-(friend_of_a_friend)
```

Since there's only one `MATCH` specified you're never going to traverse back to Adam.

For a more detailed breakdown of the differences, see this question:

[What does a comma in a Cypher query do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089692/what-does-a-comma-in-a-cypher-query-do)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand how the second query works. But I still don't get how "Adam" is part of the result of the first query since nobody is friends with "Adam". Could you please elaborate more on how the matching is done in this case?

Comment: You're not specifying a direction for your `MATCH`, and so it's following the relationship from Pernilla back to Adam

Answer (score 0):

To explain a little what @Brian Underwood mentioned.

If you can remember there are **three Relationship syntax**

> 1. -[:r1]-   undefined direction
> 2. -[:r2]->  direction outward of the node
> 3. <-[:r3]-  direction toward the node

**MATCH**

If you use a single MATCH for a pattern with or without a comma, it won't repeat the pattern.

You might ask when does a pattern will be repeated. Well, that is when you use the undefined direction. Since you didn't tell it to which direction to go, it'll go in both directions.

That is, from Adam to David; and back to; David to Adam.
So, a single Match will go to the first one, which is Adam to David.

```
#1
MATCH (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]-(friend)
MATCH (friend)-[r2:FRIEND]-(friend_of_a_friend)
RETURN friend_of_a_friend.name AS fofName
```

Will return David and Adam because it is using undefined direction.

```
#2
MATCH (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]->(friend)
MATCH (friend)-[r2:FRIEND]->(friend_of_a_friend)
RETURN friend_of_a_friend.name AS fofName
```

But this one will return only David, that is because you are using **outward direction** which can not be repeated.

Cypher query #2 is also the same as the following query

```
MATCH (user:User { name: 'Adam' })-[r1:FRIEND]-(friend),(friend)-[r2:FRIEND]-(friend_of_a_friend)
RETURN friend_of_a_friend.name AS fofName
```

Even though it is using the undefined direction, which traverses in both directions, to take only a single pattern we are using a single MATCH clause.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: One thing that not a lot of people know, you don't need the brackets if you don't want to filter on relationships.  Like `()--()`, `()-->()`, and `()<--()`

Comment: @Brain Underwood got it!!