# neo4jrb: Pulling just desired properties for performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Using ActiveNode, how can a user pull just the name, or just name and description for a node?

Example based on https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Search-and-Match

Let's expand the model as follows:

```
class Lesson
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :scheduled_time

  has_many :in, :students, origin: :lesson
  has_many :out, :teachers, type: 'taught_by'
end
```

If the desired information is "What other times is this student's teacher teaching?", we only need the times from each Lesson.
How do we use Neo4jrb to do the CYPHER query for just those properties?

Comment: (And for bonus points: Return those properties in a single array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like for the option to select the fields that you want and return them as model objects.  But I don't think that's what you're asking for (fortunately, because it's not there yet ;)

So I believe `pluck` is what you want:

```
student.lessons(:student_lesson).teachers.lessons(:other_lesson).where('student_lesson <> other_lesson').pluck(:scheduled_time)
```

This will generate the appropriate Cypher and return an array of `scheduled_time` values.

This might actually be a simpler way to do it:

```
student.lessons.teachers.lessons.pluck(:scheduled_time)
```

And normally if all of the conditions were in a single `MATCH` this should work because Cypher doesn't ever traverse the same relationship twice in a single `MATCH`.  The association chaining syntax, however, generates multiple `MATCH` clauses.  It actually used to generate a single `MATCH`, but there were issues with that (which escape me at the moment).

For a more in-depth explanation about single vs multiple matches, see this SO question:

[What does a comma in a Cypher query do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089692/what-does-a-comma-in-a-cypher-query-do)