# Neo4j find communities around nodes

Tags: neo4j

Not sure this is possible but will try asking.  I am trying to find (Person) nodes groups that share at least 5 (Action) nodes where model is

```
(p:PERSON)-[:CHAT]->(a:ACTION)
```

I can do this for showing 2 Persons groups that share +5 Actions

```
MATCH path =(p1:PERSON)-[r1:CHAT]->(a:ACTION)<-[r2:CHAT]-(p2:PERSON) 
WITH  p1, p2, count(a) as ActionCount WHERE ActionCount >= 5
RETURN (p1)-[:CHAT]->(:ACTION)<-[:CHAT]-(p2)
```

However is there a smart way to do this dynamically or using collections where there are more people in a shared group?  I am trying to identify efficient teams based on Action metrics, and flagging virtual teams if they share at least 5 actions

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you can do this by programmatically generating a query.  I'm not sure if you can do this programmatically in Cypher.  To generate a query easily I would do something like:

```
MATCH
  (a:ACTION),
  (a)<-[:CHAT]-(p1:PERSON),
  (a)<-[:CHAT]-(p2:PERSON),
  (a)<-[:CHAT]-(p3:PERSON),
  (a)<-[:CHAT]-(p4:PERSON),
  (a)<-[:CHAT]-(p5:PERSON) 
WITH  p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, count(a) as ActionCount
WHERE ActionCount >= 5
RETURN [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5], ActionCount
```

Not that you don't need the `path` and relationship variables if you're not using them later.

Comment: You might also get a combinatorial explosion as you check for more people

Comment: thanks this gave me some ideas below , however not sure why it works, but its nearly there,      `MATCH  (a:ACTION)<-[:CHAT]-(p1:PERSON), (a)<-[:CHAT]-(p2:PERSON) 
WITH  p1, p2, collect(a.ActionID) as ActionColl, count(a) as ActionCount, avg(a.Age) as ActionAge
WHERE ActionCount >= 5 and p1.PersonID < p2.PersonID
WITH   COLLECT(distinct ( p1.PersonID + '-' + p2.PersonID)) as Peeps,  ActionColl, ActionCount , ActionAge
RETURN Peeps, ActionColl, ActionCount, ActionAge ORDER BY ActionAge`

Comment: so it nearly works, where it gives all combinations of PERSONS  with combinations of at least 5 ACTIONS.  BUT.... i get multiple rows for essentially the same combination of PersonIDs  e.g. Persons [A, B, C, D, E] -- [5 actions]; Persons[A, C, D] -- [same 5 actions]; Persons [D, E] -- [same 5 actions]

Comment: It's important to remember that when you do a `MATCH`, it will find every possible way to form the match.  So you could get A and B as both p1/p2 and p2/p1.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089692/what-does-a-comma-in-a-cypher-query-do

Comment: aaah - yes, you will see in my code i tried that - the only thing i can spot, is that if the collection returns Action nodes [A, B, C, D, E] in a different order, then a new row is returned. Any idea how i can prevent this?

Comment: Maybe sorting and using distinct?  I think that you can do an `ORDER BY` with your `WITH` with the `collect` to make the items in a specific order

Comment: `MATCH  (a:ACTION)-[r:ASSIGN]->(p1:PERSON), (a)-[rr:ASSIGN]->(p2:PERSON) 
WHERE r.Relationship = 'Assigned To' and rr.Relationship = 'Assigned To'
with p1, p2, a order by a.ActionID
with p1, p2, collect(distinct a.ActionID) as ActionColl, count(a) as ActionCount ORDER BY p1.PersonID, p2.PersonID
WHERE ActionCount>=5 and p1.PersonID < p2.PersonID 
with collect(distinct p1.PersonID) as pp1, collect(distinct p2.PersonID) as pp2, ActionColl, ActionCount 
return pp1, size(pp1) as pp1Size, pp2, ActionColl, ActionCount order by HEAD(pp1)`

Comment: thanks- finally got there with all your help - didn't realise you could have so many WITH clauses , and still run the query quickly

Comment: Indeed!  Just one `WITH`s can certainly slow your query down depending on what you do with it, but you can definitely have a lot of `WITH`s in a performant way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you said this both ways (five actions per user / five users per action).  It should work the same either way:

```
MATCH (p:PERSON)-[:CHAT]->(a:ACTION)
WITH p, count(a) AS action_count
WHERE action_count >= 5
MATCH (p)-[:CHAT]->(a:ACTION)
RETURN p, collect(a)
```

I just made up what is being returned there.  You should be able to return anything that you like.

Another way to do it:

```
MATCH (p:PERSON)
WHERE size( (p)-[:CHAT]->(:ACTION) ) >= 5
WITH p
MATCH (p)-[:CHAT]->(a:ACTION)
RETURN p, collect(a)
```

Comment: let me try to explain this way.  

we want communities of Persons that share multiple Actions (i.e share at least 5 actions), swould be after a results like  :   
  
example1:  [Person1, Person2, Person3]  all chat about [Action1, Action2, Action5, Action6, Action7].  

example2:  [Person1, Person6, Person7]  all chat about [Action11, Action12, Action15, Action26, Action27].  

example3:  [Person4, Person6]  both chat about  [Action71, Action72, Action75, Action77, Action78].   

With the metrics behind the Action nodes, we can then see who the best performing combinations of Persons are.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'll give it a stab in another answer