# Cypher Query for Fork Pattern

Tags: neo4j, nlp, cypher, token

I am trying to make queries on a graph of word-tokens with relationships of which word is before the following word.  I want to query for a pattern that looks something like a fork or a Y in the graph, with a common pair of sequential words and a two different words following the pair.  For example, in a graph over Genesis 1, I might want to query for pairs of different words following the phrase "over every", which could be followed by either "living" or "creeping".

Rather than return all words following the phrase, it would be better if both the different words were returned in the same record.  The goal of this query would be to bring out the implicit relationship between living and creeping as "sibling" words, which would be easier if returned together in this way.

My initial thought would just be to do two matches on the pattern of words following the phrase, and union them together to merge the different words.  But I was hoping there might be a more direct way I just don't know about.  Does this exist?[image]

**Edit**

Sample query to help get at the idea:

```
MATCH
    (o {text: "OVER"})-[:BEFORE]->(e {text: "EVERY"})-[:BEFORE]->(t), 
    (o)-[:BEFORE]->(e)-[:BEFORE]->(c)
CREATE (l)-[:SIBLING]->(c)
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more about the desired result format? You can use `collect()` in order to collect nodes or node properties, but it would be helpful to know how you want to use the results, whether it's a particular return structure, or if the graph visualization is more important.

Comment: It would seem https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090944/1399272 is perhaps what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090944/1399272) of [What does a comma in a Cypher query do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34089692/1399272) was a bit closer than my initial approach.  This involved using commas to effect a fork in the pattern, so instead of the above `MATCH` clause

```
MATCH
    (o {text: "OVER"})-[:BEFORE]->(e {text: "EVERY"})-[:BEFORE]->(t), 
    (o)-[:BEFORE]->(e)-[:BEFORE]->(c)
```

I would simply do

```
MATCH
    (o {text: "OVER"})-[:BEFORE]->(e {text: "EVERY"})-[:BEFORE]->(t), 
    (e)-[:BEFORE]->(c)
```

No need to re-match `(o)-[:BEFORE]->(e)`.

Using the second `MATCH` clause did get me the fork pattern I was trying to match, however the results lacked an appropriate level of context -- instead of returning all words following the phrase "OVER EVERY," it simply returned all the words following "EVERY."  Upon further reflection this made sense, since that was indeed what I was asking it to do; match "OVER", "EVERY", and any two words following "EVERY."  The only context I had in the graph was which word followed which; there was no context regarding which word followed which phrase.

To fix this, I ended up re-making my graph, giving it the full phrasal context.  The original graph model simply had nodes of all the unique words in the document, with relationships of which unique word was before another -- good data for a simple bi-gon Markov tree, bad for longer n-gons.  The new graph model still contains a set of nodes that represent the document's unique words, as well as another set of nodes that represents each individual word.  The individual words are related to each other in the order they appear in the document, which ends up looking like a long train of word nodes.  The unique words are related in terms of which are siblings of a fork with a common phrase three word nodes long.  With the proper phrasal context thus included, I was able to obtain the sibling relationships I was originally looking for.

## Code

### Original model

Unique word nodes (sample):

```
CREATE (CommaChar:Token {text:','})
CREATE (PeriodChar:Token {text:'.'})
CREATE (ColonChar:Token {text:':'})
CREATE (SemicolonChar:Token {text:';'})
CREATE (A:Token {text:'A'})
CREATE (Above:Token {text:'ABOVE'})
CREATE (Abundantly:Token {text:'ABUNDANTLY'})
CREATE (After:Token {text:'AFTER'})
CREATE (Air:Token {text:'AIR'})
CREATE (All:Token {text:'ALL'})
CREATE (Also:Token {text:'ALSO'})
CREATE (And:Token {text:'AND'})
CREATE (Appear:Token {text:'APPEAR'})
CREATE (Be:Token {text:'BE'})
CREATE (Bearing:Token {text:'BEARING'})
...
CREATE (Whales:Token {text:'WHALES'})
CREATE (Wherein:Token {text:'WHEREIN'})
CREATE (Which:Token {text:'WHICH'})
CREATE (Whose:Token {text:'WHOSE'})
CREATE (Winged:Token {text:'WINGED'})
CREATE (Without:Token {text:'WITHOUT'})
CREATE (Years:Token {text:'YEARS'})
CREATE (Yielding:Token {text:'YIELDING'})
CREATE (You:Token {text:'YOU'})
```

`BEFORE` relationships:

```
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Beginning)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Created)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Without)-[:BEFORE]->(Form)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Void)-[:BEFORE]->(SemicolonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Darkness)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Face)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Deep)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Spirit)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Moved)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Face)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(There)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(There)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Divided)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(From)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Darkness)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Called)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Darkness)-[:BEFORE]->(He)-[:BEFORE]->(Called)-[:BEFORE]->(Night)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Evening)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Morning)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(First)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(There)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(A)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Midst)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Divide)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(From)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Made)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Divided)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(Which)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(Under)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(From)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(Which)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(Above)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Called)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Evening)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Morning)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Second)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(Under)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(Gathered)-[:BEFORE]->(Together)-[:BEFORE]->(Unto)-[:BEFORE]->(One)-[:BEFORE]->(Place)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Dry)-[:BEFORE]->(Land)-[:BEFORE]->(Appear)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Called)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Dry)-[:BEFORE]->(Land)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(SemicolonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Gathering)-[:BEFORE]->(Together)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(Called)-[:BEFORE]->(He)-[:BEFORE]->(Seas)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(Bring)-[:BEFORE]->(Forth)-[:BEFORE]->(Grass)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Herb)-[:BEFORE]->(Yielding)-[:BEFORE]->(Seed)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fruit)-[:BEFORE]->(Tree)-[:BEFORE]->(Yielding)-[:BEFORE]->(Fruit)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Whose)-[:BEFORE]->(Seed)-[:BEFORE]->(Is)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(Itself)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(Brought)-[:BEFORE]->(Forth)-[:BEFORE]->(Grass)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Herb)-[:BEFORE]->(Yielding)-[:BEFORE]->(Seed)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Tree)-[:BEFORE]->(Yielding)-[:BEFORE]->(Fruit)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Whose)-[:BEFORE]->(Seed)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(Itself)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Evening)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Morning)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Third)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(There)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(Lights)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Divide)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(From)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Night)-[:BEFORE]->(SemicolonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(For)-[:BEFORE]->(Signs)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(For)-[:BEFORE]->(Seasons)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(For)-[:BEFORE]->(Days)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Years)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(For)-[:BEFORE]->(Lights)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Give)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Made)-[:BEFORE]->(Two)-[:BEFORE]->(Great)-[:BEFORE]->(Lights)-[:BEFORE]->(SemicolonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Greater)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Rule)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Lesser)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Rule)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Night)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(He)-[:BEFORE]->(Made)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Stars)-[:BEFORE]->(Also)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Set)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Give)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Rule)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Night)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Divide)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Light)-[:BEFORE]->(From)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Darkness)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Evening)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Morning)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fourth)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(Bring)-[:BEFORE]->(Forth)-[:BEFORE]->(Abundantly)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Moving)-[:BEFORE]->(Creature)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(Hath)-[:BEFORE]->(Life)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Fowl)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(May)-[:BEFORE]->(Fly)-[:BEFORE]->(Above)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Open)-[:BEFORE]->(Firmament)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Created)-[:BEFORE]->(Great)-[:BEFORE]->(Whales)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Living)-[:BEFORE]->(Creature)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(Moveth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Which)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(Brought)-[:BEFORE]->(Forth)-[:BEFORE]->(Abundantly)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(Their)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Winged)-[:BEFORE]->(Fowl)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Blessed)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Saying)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(Fruitful)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Multiply)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Fill)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Waters)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Seas)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(Fowl)-[:BEFORE]->(Multiply)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Evening)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Morning)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fifth)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(Bring)-[:BEFORE]->(Forth)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Living)-[:BEFORE]->(Creature)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Cattle)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Creeping)-[:BEFORE]->(Thing)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Beast)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Made)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Beast)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Cattle)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(Their)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Thing)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(Creepeth)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Kind)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(Us)-[:BEFORE]->(Make)-[:BEFORE]->(Man)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(Our)-[:BEFORE]->(Image)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(After)-[:BEFORE]->(Our)-[:BEFORE]->(Likeness)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Let)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(Have)-[:BEFORE]->(Dominion)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fish)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Sea)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fowl)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Air)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Cattle)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(All)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Creeping)-[:BEFORE]->(Thing)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(Creepeth)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Created)-[:BEFORE]->(Man)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(His)-[:BEFORE]->(Own)-[:BEFORE]->(Image)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Image)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Created)-[:BEFORE]->(He)-[:BEFORE]->(Him)-[:BEFORE]->(SemicolonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Male)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Female)-[:BEFORE]->(Created)-[:BEFORE]->(He)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Blessed)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(Unto)-[:BEFORE]->(Them)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(Fruitful)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Multiply)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Replenish)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Subdue)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Have)-[:BEFORE]->(Dominion)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fish)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Sea)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fowl)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Air)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Over)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Living)-[:BEFORE]->(Thing)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(Moveth)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Said)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Behold)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(I)-[:BEFORE]->(Have)-[:BEFORE]->(Given)-[:BEFORE]->(You)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Herb)-[:BEFORE]->(Bearing)-[:BEFORE]->(Seed)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Which)-[:BEFORE]->(Is)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Face)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(All)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Tree)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(In)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Which)-[:BEFORE]->(Is)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Fruit)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(A)-[:BEFORE]->(Tree)-[:BEFORE]->(Yielding)-[:BEFORE]->(Seed)-[:BEFORE]->(SemicolonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(You)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Shall)-[:BEFORE]->(Be)-[:BEFORE]->(For)-[:BEFORE]->(Meat)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Beast)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Fowl)-[:BEFORE]->(Of)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Air)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(To)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Thing)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(Creepeth)-[:BEFORE]->(Upon)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Earth)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Wherein)-[:BEFORE]->(There)-[:BEFORE]->(Is)-[:BEFORE]->(Life)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(I)-[:BEFORE]->(Have)-[:BEFORE]->(Given)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Green)-[:BEFORE]->(Herb)-[:BEFORE]->(For)-[:BEFORE]->(Meat)-[:BEFORE]->(ColonChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(So)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
CREATE (PhraseStart)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(God)-[:BEFORE]->(Saw)-[:BEFORE]->(Every)-[:BEFORE]->(Thing)-[:BEFORE]->(That)-[:BEFORE]->(He)-[:BEFORE]->(Had)-[:BEFORE]->(Made)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(Behold)-[:BEFORE]->(CommaChar)-[:BEFORE]->(It)-[:BEFORE]->(Was)-[:BEFORE]->(Very)-[:BEFORE]->(Good)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Evening)-[:BEFORE]->(And)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Morning)-[:BEFORE]->(Were)-[:BEFORE]->(The)-[:BEFORE]->(Sixth)-[:BEFORE]->(Day)-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar)-[:BEFORE]->(PhraseEnd)
```

Sibling query:

```
MATCH
    (a:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(b:Token)-[:BEFORE]-(c:Token),
    (b)-[:BEFORE]->(d:Token)
RETURN c, d
```

Returns all pairs of tokens with both tokens in pair following `b` token.

### Current model

Unique words nodes (to be made siblings):

```
CREATE (CommaChar:SibToken {text:','})
CREATE (PeriodChar:SibToken {text:'.'})
CREATE (ColonChar:SibToken {text:':'})
CREATE (SemicolonChar:SibToken {text:';'})
CREATE (A:SibToken {text:'A'})
CREATE (Above:SibToken {text:'ABOVE'})
CREATE (Abundantly:SibToken {text:'ABUNDANTLY'})
CREATE (After:SibToken {text:'AFTER'})
CREATE (Air:SibToken {text:'AIR'})
CREATE (All:SibToken {text:'ALL'})
CREATE (Also:SibToken {text:'ALSO'})
CREATE (And:SibToken {text:'AND'})
CREATE (Appear:SibToken {text:'APPEAR'})
CREATE (Be:SibToken {text:'BE'})
CREATE (Bearing:SibToken {text:'BEARING'})
...
CREATE (Whales:SibToken {text:'WHALES'})
CREATE (Wherein:SibToken {text:'WHEREIN'})
CREATE (Which:SibToken {text:'WHICH'})
CREATE (Whose:SibToken {text:'WHOSE'})
CREATE (Winged:SibToken {text:'WINGED'})
CREATE (Without:SibToken {text:'WITHOUT'})
CREATE (Years:SibToken {text:'YEARS'})
CREATE (Yielding:SibToken {text:'YIELDING'})
CREATE (You:SibToken {text:'YOU'})
```

Individual words connected (sample):

```
CREATE (In0:Token {text: "IN", id: 0})-[:BEFORE]->(The1:Token {text: "THE", id: 1})-[:BEFORE]->(Beginning2:Token {text: "BEGINNING", id: 2})-[:BEFORE]->(God3:Token {text: "GOD", id: 3})-[:BEFORE]->(Created4:Token {text: "CREATED", id: 4})-[:BEFORE]->(The5:Token {text: "THE", id: 5})-[:BEFORE]->(Heaven6:Token {text: "HEAVEN", id: 6})-[:BEFORE]->(And7:Token {text: "AND", id: 7})-[:BEFORE]->(The8:Token {text: "THE", id: 8})-[:BEFORE]->(Earth9:Token {text: "EARTH", id: 9})-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar10:Token {text: ".", id: 10})-[:BEFORE]->(And11:Token {text: "AND", id: 11})...(And910:Token {text: "AND", id: 910})-[:BEFORE]->(The911:Token {text: "THE", id: 911})-[:BEFORE]->(Evening912:Token {text: "EVENING", id: 912})-[:BEFORE]->(And913:Token {text: "AND", id: 913})-[:BEFORE]->(The914:Token {text: "THE", id: 914})-[:BEFORE]->(Morning915:Token {text: "MORNING", id: 915})-[:BEFORE]->(Were916:Token {text: "WERE", id: 916})-[:BEFORE]->(The917:Token {text: "THE", id: 917})-[:BEFORE]->(Sixth918:Token {text: "SIXTH", id: 918})-[:BEFORE]->(Day919:Token {text: "DAY", id: 919})-[:BEFORE]->(PeriodChar920:Token {text: ".", id: 920})
```

Sibling query:

```
MATCH (a1:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(b1:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(c1:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(d1:Token)
MATCH (a2:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(b2:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(c2:Token)-[:BEFORE]->(d2:Token)
MATCH (s1:SibToken)
MATCH (s2:SibToken)
WHERE a1.text = a2.text AND b1.text = b2.text AND c1.text = c2.text AND d1.text < d2.text AND s1.text = d1.text AND s2.text = d2.text
CREATE (s1)-[:SIBLING]->(s2)
```

Query results graph:

[image: Full Sibling Graph]

Particularly interesting cliques:

[image: Verb Cluster]

[image: Days and Nouns Clusters]

Answer (score 1):

What about collections of words?

I'll add labels here, using :Word for now (you should be using labels, and indexes if possible)

```
MATCH
    (o:Word {text: "OVER"})-[:BEFORE]->(e:Word {text: "EVERY"})-[:BEFORE]->(next)
RETURN collect(next.text) as nextWords
```

Comment: OK, just tried this.  Didn't know about the `collect` function, will have to keep that in mind.  However, I don't think this is quite what I'm after.  I want to be able to operate on a pair of sibling nodes that are `RETURN`ed, whereas this gives me a list of nodes' texts.

Comment: How about using `collect(next)` instead? That should satisfy what you're after: `it would be better if both the different words were returned in the same record.`

Comment: That's closer, but I still want to limit it to just two so that I can form a sibling relationship between them.  Ended up figuring something out -- I'd be interested in hearing your thoughts on whether I'm missing something to further simplify the process.

Comment: What about if there's more than two at that point? Do you want all combinations of two from the set of possible words?

Comment: Yes. The main objective was to make the sibling relationships, so unless I can make one CREATE relationship clause relating more than two nodes at once (is this possible?), I'd need to instead relate every two possible nodes. I do a basic less-than comparison of the result nodes' texts to ensure that not only do I not relate the same node to itself, but I also only make the sibling relationship between any two nodes once.