# Combine two merges into one in the Cypher language

Tags: neo4j, merge, cypher

I'm trying to make a Cypher which merges more edges than I can manage to put into the ASCII art of the Cypher language.

**TLDR;**
How to accomplish this merge:

```
MERGE (a)-[:REL1]->(b:B)-[:REL2]->(c), (b)-[:REL3]->(d)
```

I have these simplified cypher queries to describe the problem:

```
// ensure required nodes exists
MATCH (a:A {id: "<uuid1>"})
MATCH (c:C {id: "<uuid2>"})
MATCH (d:D {id: "<uuid3>"})

// Make B connect the nodes
MERGE (a)-[:REL1]->(b:B)-[:REL2]->(c)
MERGE (b)-[:REL3]->(d) // <- thats the main problem - a seperate merge to make this relation, but it should be part of the first merge.

// Conclude
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

This query will work, but when it's being called multiple times, b is being reused. By that I mean, that multiple of these relations is made from the same b: `(b)-:REL3->(d)`. That's not allowed in my system, since I should be able to delete b, and only affect exactly what was created by the first call.

To ensure that b is unique then, I could do this:

```
// ensure required nodes exists
MATCH (a:A {id: "<uuid1>"})
MATCH (c:C {id: "<uuid2>"})
MATCH (d:D {id: "<uuid3>"})

// ensure unique B
CREATE (b:B)

// Make B connect the nodes
MERGE (a)-[:REL1]->(b)-[:REL2]->(c)
MERGE (b)-[:REL3]->(d)

// Conclude
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

The problem with this one is, that each time it's called, a new B-node is created, even if the path already existed. Now that's just duplicated data, and I dont want that either.

I could fix that by adding a `WITH/WHERE` statement

```
// ensure required nodes exists
MATCH (a:A {id: "<uuid1>"})
MATCH (c:C {id: "<uuid2>"})
MATCH (d:D {id: "<uuid3>"})

OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:REL1]->(existingB:B)-[:REL2]->(c)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[:REL3]->(d)

WITH a,exisingB,c,d
WHERE existingB is null // query ends here and I end up with zero rows returned

// ensure unique B
CREATE (b:B)

// Make B connect the nodes
MERGE (a)-[:REL1]->(b)-[:REL2]->(c)
MERGE (b)-[:REL3]->(d)

// Conclude
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

However, now the query doesn't return a,b,c,d - which I want it to.

So to sum it up, I want a query which:

1. Always returns.
2. Creates a new `b node` which combines a,c and d, if it doesn't already exist.
3. If it does exist, find it and return it instead.

This is quite simple when dealing with simple merges: `MATCH > MERGE > RETURN`. The only thing that twists my mind, is the fact that I can't see how to do this with a single MERGE command.

As far as I can tell, combinations of multiple MERGE commands isn't possible, but I hope that someone has a solution for this.

## UPDATED with real life example

Let's start by creating the required nodes in our access management example:

```
// create required nodes
CREATE (:Human {name:"Human A"})
CREATE (:Human {name:"Human B"})
CREATE (:Human {name:"Human C"})
CREATE (:Scope {name:"read:email"})
```

Now that should leave us with this:
[image: Required nodes for example]

Now I want to grant Human A access to read:email on behalf of Human B:

```
// grant "Human A" access to "read:email" on behalf of "Human B" - aka let Human A read Human B's email address
MATCH (humanA:Human {name:"Human A"})
MATCH (readEmail:Scope {name:"read:email"})
MATCH (humanB:Human {name:"Human B"})

MERGE (humanA)-[:IS_GRANTED]->(gr:Grant:Rule)-[:GRANTS]->(readEmail)
MERGE (gr)-[:ON_BEHALF_OF]->(humanB)
```

This brings us in the following state:
[image: Human A granted read:email to Human B]

So far, everything is good. I can rerun the query and the same exact state is kept.

Now I want Human A to have read:email to Huamn C as well. Same query, new "on behalf of".

```
// grant "Human A" access to "read:email" on behalf of "Human C" - aka let Human A read Human C's email address
MATCH (humanA:Human {name:"Human A"})
MATCH (readEmail:Scope {name:"read:email"})
MATCH (humanC:Human {name:"Human C"})

MERGE (humanA)-[:IS_GRANTED]->(gr:Grant:Rule)-[:GRANTS]->(readEmail)
MERGE (gr)-[:ON_BEHALF_OF]->(humanC)
```

Now the problem arrives:
[image: Reuse of grant rule problem]

The Grant Rule is being reused, which is a problem for multiple reasons, but lets just state the obvious one: When I want to remove Human A's access to Human B's email, it's also removed to Human C, since they share the same rule.

Now one might say, why not merge "on behalf of" first to avoid this problem?
Let's try and start over, but adding another scope "read:phone":

```
// create required nodes
CREATE (:Human {name:"Human A"})
CREATE (:Human {name:"Human B"})
CREATE (:Human {name:"Human C"})
CREATE (:Scope {name:"read:email"})
CREATE (:Scope {name:"read:phone"})
```

[image: Required nodes for example]

And try moving it around:

```
// grant "Human A" access to "read:email" on behalf of "Human B" - aka let Human A read Human B's email address
MATCH (humanA:Human {name:"Human A"})
MATCH (readEmail:Scope {name:"read:email"})
MATCH (humanB:Human {name:"Human B"})

MERGE (humanA)-[:IS_GRANTED]->(gr:Grant:Rule)-[:ON_BEHALF_OF]->(humanB)
MERGE (gr)-[:GRANTS]->(readEmail)
```

Just as last time, we end up with a correct state:

[image: Human A granted read:email to Human B]

Now I want to grant Human A access to Huamn B's read:phone aswell:

```
// grant "Human A" access to "read:phone" on behalf of "Human B" - aka let Human A read Human B's phone number
MATCH (humanA:Human {name:"Human A"})
MATCH (readPhone:Scope {name:"read:phone"})
MATCH (humanB:Human {name:"Human B"})

MERGE (humanA)-[:IS_GRANTED]->(gr:Grant:Rule)-[:ON_BEHALF_OF]->(humanC)
MERGE (gr)-[:GRANTS]->(readPhone)
```

Now this gives us this:

[image: reusing of grant rule]

That's incorrect. Now I can only delete all or nothing from Human A to Human B.

That was a lot, but I hope it gave some insights to the problem.

Comment: So the crux if ensuring `b:B` is unique but you don't have a way to identify whether it is unique other than its `REL1`, `REL2`, `REL3` connections to `A`, `B` and `C`? i.e. you don't have a uuid to uniquely find or create B?

Comment: @DaveBennett correct, `b:B` must only exist once with `REL1, REL2, REL3`. Even if I added a uuid to `b:B`, I wouldn't know which one I should merge, 'cause the relations is the main thing defining it.

Comment: The last example, with the read:phone and read:email nodes, looks about right. If you need to delete a specific granted capability, you can match to the pattern in question, then delete the :GRANTS relationship to the read:phone privilege, check the degree of the :Grant node, and only delete that node if no more :GRANTS relationships are present. Or, if you only need a grant to have only 1 privilege, you could have a property on the grant node for that...and either let that alone determine it, or have both. That allows the property to aid your MERGE, then you can MERGE to the privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATED (TWICE)]

This trick may work for your "3-legged-merge" (to coin a term). The second illustration in your question shows an example of the desired outcome of a 3-legged-merge, where a given `Scope` node has relationships to 3 specific nodes and ONLY those 3 nodes.

The trick is this: add 2 properties (or 3, see Notes below) to each `Grant` that uniquely identify the associated `Scope`, and the associated `Human` on whose behalf the grant is acting. This is admittedly redundant information if you also have relationships to the actual `Scope` and the `Human` nodes, but it should ensure that you can use `MERGE` to create a unique `Grant` node for each unique set of 3 legs.

For example, to properly perform the second query (in your update), assuming that `name` values are unique:

```
MATCH (humanA:Human {name:"Human A"})
MATCH (readEmail:Scope {name:"read:email"})
MATCH (humanC:Human {name:"Human C"})

MERGE (humanA)-[:IS_GRANTED]->(g:Grant:Rule {for: humanC.name, scope: readEmail.name})
MERGE (g)-[:ON_BEHALF_OF]->(humanC)
MERGE (g)-[:GRANTS]->(readEmail)
```

Notes:

- The first `MERGE` ensures the `g` node is only associated with "Human A", so there is no need to add a third property to `g` with the unique identifier for "Human A" -- **if and only if** you always start your 3-legged-merge with the `IS_GRANTED` relationship.

  However, if you could sometimes create `Grant` nodes starting with one of the other "legs", then you'd need to have a property for each leg.
- You will have to keep the `Grant` properties even after you create the associated relationships, so that future 3-legged merges will work properly.
- Strictly speaking, you actually do not need to perform either of the last 2 `MERGE`s, since the `Grant` node will contain enough information to get the missing (virtual) legs dynamically, as needed. For example, to get the `Scope`s involving "Human A" on behalf of "Human C":

  ```
  MATCH
    (:Human {name:"Human A"})-[:IS_GRANTED]->(g {for: "Human C"}),
    (scope:Scope {name: g.scope})
  RETURN scope
  ```

  This is less efficient than having the actual relationships but saves on storage. Creating appropriate [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) (e.g., on ":Scope(name)" in this case) would reduce the speed penalty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cybersam. I'm sorry, I didn't grasp the concept completly with comma in matches as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089692/what-does-a-comma-in-a-cypher-query-do when i simplified the queries.
I know exactly which single nodes  A, C and D is. I've updated the queries to reflect that. I'm not working on the entire graph, but rather on 3 exact nodes which I need to connect together through a new node. I hope that makes my problem clearer.

Comment: If MERGE worked like MATCH, this is the query I wanted: `MERGE (a)-[:REL1]->(b:B)-[:REL2]->(c), (b)-[:REL3]->(d)`

Comment: I see why you would go this way. I'll need to update my question when I get a chance to make the problem more clear with a real life example.

But basicly, `a:A` can have many `b:B's`, but only one of each pointing to the combination of `c:C` and `d:D`.

It's used for a pattern in an access mangement system.
`identity1:A-[:IS_GRANTED]->(grantRule:B)-[:GRANTS]->(scope:C), (grantRule)-[:ON_BEHALF_OF]->(identity2:D)`. I will try to update the question with a section describing this. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: That would work even though it's a bit hacked. As I see it, there is currently 3 options available: 1. your solution with tmp data, 2. (maybe) optional delete then merge to ensure only one exists, 3. split into 2 queries, first match and return if found, then create if not. I might add an answer myself later when I've tested it and see whats works best, but I'll accept your answer since it's one of the solutions for my problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Note that in my proposal the added properties are not "temporary" (unless you know you will never need to do any more 3-legged merges).

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a bad way to describe it in the comment. I understand your solution to the problem though.